# dpdk flow type, pctype, rss and pktgen questions

Tags: packet-capture, dpdk

As a new DPDK user, I am grateful if someone can help answer following basic questions.

- I see from the document and source code, there are packet type (e.g.,
  172 IPV4 GTPU IPV4 TCP PAY4), packet classification type (pctype),
  and flow type (e.g., 0 to 22). What are these types and their
  relations?
- DPDK has to map hardware type (pctype?) to the software
  flow type to run RSS. Why is this and how it is done?
- DPDK has [mempool](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/mempool_lib.html) and it can allocate interleaved memory based on channels and ranks. But I don't understand how it is done (e.g., in the two figures in the link).
- Last question is about the pktgen. Can it send e.g., 10 packets and stop? Or can it send pcap file once after it's loaded? I found it just keeps sending packets over and over.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can it send e.g., 10 packets and stop?
Yes

**set 0 count 10**

While 0 is the port number

We've used pktgen-dpdk to send 1000000 packets and the remote could receive such number of packets.